# Prestashop 1.6.x show empty page whenever product is disbale

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed prestashop 1.6.1 with around 1200 products.

I see in google webmaster all disable products are listed in Craw error, when I open that link it shows blank page.

In admin->catalog->product-> I have set disable true & show 404 page when disable.

Can you please help me, what I am missing. Thank you.

Edit: Which is better option with SEO point of view 404, 301 or 302 ?

Comment: You have to set a 301 or 302 for disabled product.

Comment: "which is better"   there isn't a better. Just use the appropriate response for the actual situation.
404= product is gone and NEVER coming back
301= product is permanently moved
302=product is temporarily moved. // if just out of stock, likely best choice

Comment: If you have blank page please enable errors: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information-blank-page-500-internal-server-error/